# Java regex match across words having apostrophe

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence "no it's all right lag" where I am trying to detected a pattern "no lag". My regex is `no + (\\s\\w*?\\s?){1,3} + lag`. This fails. However if my sentence is "no its all right lag" (note that the word its is not having the apostrophe), then the match succeeds. Can anyone suggest how can i ignore the apostrophe in the window. 
I am using java pattern `matcher`.

Comment: I can remove apostrophe from the sentence, but it will lead to other complications in my system. So I will not prefer to do that.

Comment: Your question lacks exact requirements. You will get a ton of relevant and irrelevant answers because of that.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new character class with the [] notation, instead of having \w you should use [\w'] making the entire regex "no(\s[\w']*?\s?){1,3}lag" as a Java String.

Also for developing regular expressions I would recommend this site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: And what if there is a comma? Or more characters that OP does not know of yet? Adding more and more characters to a character class is a solution for one concrete string only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew then just include the comma in the class. [\w',]

Comment: Thanks the above regex works. Since I take care of other special characters, this works for me in pretty much all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think just    no(.*)lag  pattern    will work. If I understood right.

Comment: This should do the trick with a no-greedy version which would match 1st occurence only: `no.*?lag`

Comment: Yes.. I tried and seems working.  str.replaceAll ("no (.*)lag", "A")   ==>   A ,   am I doing something wrong?( when str is "no man lag no man lag..."